# Is there an autocomplete (__git_complete) for "git push origin"

Tags: bash, git, alias, git-bash, bash-completion

trying to create git alias `alias gpo = "git push origin"` but there doesn't seem to be a `__git_complete` for git push with an origin, `__git_complete gpo _git_push` wants to autocomplete the origin even though it's included in the alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me (complete references — local and remote branches, and tags):

```bash
alias gpo="git push origin"

_gpo_comp_refs() {
    __load_completion git
    local cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    COMPREPLY=(`compgen -W "$(__git_refs)" -- "$cur"`)
}

complete -F _gpo_comp_refs gpo
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to be working for me, will get ```$ gpo bash: __load_completion: command not found
bash: __load_completion: command not found
```
Though it might be something on my machine, also sorry for leaving you hanging for a few days, weekend things.

Comment: @Jae [`__load_completion`](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/38622e6fce1fdb3e07db29b71be6478e6eb70a9d/bash_completion#L2588) is a function from [`bash-completion`](https://launchpad.net/bash-completion) package. If you don't use `bash-completion` you can remove the line from my code. On the other hand if you don't use the package what completion do you use?

Comment: pretty sure i'm using bash completion and it works in other places, but not with this code for some reason, let me try to reconfigure and get back to you.

Comment: @Jae Surely you use bash completion but do you use the full `bash-completion` package? Or just [`git-completion.bash`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash)?

Comment: pretty sure its just git-completion.bash, is bash-completion available for windows and if so how do I install that package. Not seeing much online that's not just git-completion.bash

Comment: For `git-bash` I think you can clone https://github.com/scop/bash-completion and source its main loader in your `~/.bashrc`: https://github.com/scop/bash-completion#installation

Comment: For just `git-completion.bash` remove (comment out) the line `__load_completion git`.